# Loading a pdf file in pdf.js using a POST request

Tags: javascript, post, pdf.js

I'm using PDFJS version 1.0.935 from the bower pdfjs-dist package.

Is there a way to load a document with POST instead of GET? I'm looking in the pdf.worker.js file, line 1672, and it says:

```
  xhr.open('GET', this.url);
```

This is the only xhr.open found in this package, so I guess it is hardcoded. However, there are posts on the net like this one (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/1136) that say that POST was implemented a few years ago.

I would expect a 'requestMethod' or similar parameter for PDFJS.getDocument(), in addition to parameters like 'url' and 'httpHeaders'.

Thank you!

Comment: PDF.js contains the optimization for range request to speed up initial page display. 'POST' cannot do that. You can POST data yourself and use getDocument overload with binary data instead of url.

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/1136 is applicable for the addon/extension only